# how to +1 to the MAX record from a field

Tags: php

.i have the following code:

```
$task_id = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(task_id) from it_task");
echo $task_id;
```

.what I want to do is to get the highest value from a field named task_id on the table it_task. Instead of getting a result which is an integer I get "Resource id #5". how do i get around this?

Comment: I suggest you read up on some MySQL/PHP tutorials as this is pretty basic stuff. Just looking at the PHP manual entry for `mysql_query` would give you a good example of what to do.

Comment: BTW, I hope you're not trying to use this to generate *"the next"* id for a new task instead of using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: @deceze - oh yes I am, it's because i can't use the AUTO_INCREMENT function because it is already assigned to another field.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're doing something very wrong that will eventually bite you in the rear end and which you should better open a new question about, detailing your problem to use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_query generates a resource which you then have to read using another mysql_ function. In this case you'll need a 2nd line to read from the query's result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(task_id) from it_task");
$task_id = mysql_result($result, 0, 0); // get the first row, first column
echo $task_id;
```

Comment: .oh i totally forgot about that! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Any problem here??? In my postgres sql, I can have:

```
select max(task_id)+1 as max from it_task;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `mysql_query` always returns a resource (unless it returns `false`), which you have to work on using one of the `mysql_` functions like [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).